# Why does a macroscopic chrystal reflect the atomic lattice structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

When we look at the macroscopic forms of crystals you can see how the atomic lattice is built up. The most common example is salt (sodium chloride), the visible cubic crystals reflecting the cubic lattice.
If a crystal is forming, why doesn't this happen in a random way? Why the growth follows the atomic lattice structure?

There are many other examples of crystals, like quartz or this strange form of pyrite (almost perfect squares are visible)

[image]

The structure grows according to the structure of the basic atoms in the crystal (you could even say the crystal is one big molecule). So the condition for the macroscopic structure to develop is that there exists an atomic base unit with has the same form as the macroscopic crystal (like a cube in the case of sodium chloride).

Why don't random forms develop, like the forms of rocks? Is there some evening process going on which pulls random growth back in structured growth?

Comment: this may help https://opentextbc.ca/chemistry/chapter/10-6-lattice-structures-in-crystalline-solids/   or this  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Inorganic_Chemistry/06%3A_Metals_and_Alloys-_Structure_Bonding_Electronic_and_Magnetic_Properties/6.02%3A_Unit_Cells_and_Crystal_Structures